# Android Whatsapp API for being notified when a contact is online

Tags: android, api, notifications, whatsapp

I am wondering if Whatsapp application provides an android API that will help in logging when a contact is online. In other words, can a third party application interact with Whatsapp to record when someone comes online?

Comment: Hi, If you have any progress on this, please let know thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012) you can only send an Intent to Whatsapp, but there is no API to connect to the app and get information from it.